# Newly set PIN doesn't unlock the screen

Tags: xiaomi, locked-out, bugs

#### TL;DR

There was no screen lock. I tried setting `1234` as a PIN. Now the screen is locked, asking for a 4-digit PIN. `1234` won't unlock it. But it's the right PIN since trying any other PIN multiple times will completely lock the screen for 30 seconds, while `1234` won't. More weird stuff happened, see below.

#### What happened

Over the last few months I haven't used any screen lock on non-rooted my Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro. (I had used a PIN as well as a PIN together with fingerprint recognition in the past, without any problems.) Yesterday I tried to manage some password saved at my Google account, and I got a prompt saying that I have to set a screen lock in order to continue. I agreed, I was presented with the screen lock options and I opted for a 4-digit PIN, let's say `1234`, which I entered twice (the second one for confirmation). After that, I got back to the password manager of my Google account.

**Fact #1:** When I tried to manage some password, I got the same prompt as the first time, asking me to set a screen lock if I wanted to continue!

I agreed and I opted again for a PIN.

**Fact #2:** This time I was asked for my old PIN in order to set a new one, despite **Fact #1**!

**Fact #3:** `1234` was not accepted.

At that point I gave up, thinking that I could just manage my Google account passwords using some other device. And then I turned off my phone screen. And now the screen is locked, asking for a 4-digit PIN. If I enter any PIN other than `1234` then, after 5 attempts (or just 1 attempt if the process is repeated some times), I get a penalty of 30 seconds during which I'm not allowed to enter anything. But...

**Fact #4:** I can enter `1234` as many times as I want, without ever getting any penalty! But the screen won't get unlocked.

#### My questions

- Is there any way to unlock my phone without losing my data?
- If not, is there a way to copy the data from my phone before resetting it?
- Out of curiosity, does anyone have any plausible hypothesis for what happened that is consistent with the forementioned Facts?

#### What I have tried

- Rebooting the phone.
- When I get the 30 second penalty, a "Forgot password?" button appears. But this only allows me to set a new lock after I erase all data on my device.
- I visited [www.google.com/android/find](http://www.google.com/android/find) which presented my with three options: play sound, secure device, erase device. I selected the second one, hoping it would let me set a new screen lock, but it did no such thing.
- I used the website of Google Play to install an app named [Clear Mobile Password PIN Help](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sendgroupsms.MobilePhoneUnlockHelp) on my device. This didn't seem to help either.
- Connecting my phone to my PC via USB. Unfortunately it gets in the mode "Charging only". I tried running `adb devices -l` from my PC, on the off chance that I had the dev mode activated, but no luck.
- Entering into Safe Mode. Again, `1234` won't unlock the screen.

I should note that for the last few weeks my device kept complaining of low storage space. At first I thought that this could be the source of the problem, but then I was able to install an app, my emails kept coming to the device (I can see the notifications), and I was able to shoot photos. So the storage isn't entirely full.

Comment: no plausible hypothesis, sounds like a major bug. what MIUI version is this? do you have bootloader unlocked?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot in safe mode? When rebooting press an holder the "Shut Down" button and you should get this option.

Comment: @alecxs I'm not sure about the MIUI version and I don't think I have a way to find out right now, right? I haven't unlocked anything, but I was able to go into fastboot mode by powering off my phone and then pressing and holding the power button together with the volume down button. Could that help?

Comment: fastboot is helpful if bootloader is unlocked. your device is locked, nothing you can do. Try safe mode as suggested

Comment: @Robert I just got into safe mode (I had to press and hold the volume button at when the loading screen appeared during booting), but no luck.

Comment: @alexcs Is there anything I can try when I get into safe mode other than entering the PIN?

Comment: there is a hacky way by-passing bootloader lock flashing modified splash partition from EDL mode for [Redmi 5A](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3772381). userdata partition is encrypted with *default_password* and TWRP can decrypt without PIN. unfortunately that method is not available for other devices, only expert could try. Nevertheless you can check [micloud](https://i.mi.com/?_locale=en) to get some data back